# Issue while insert data in mysql database deployed in rds

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, twitterapi-python

The thing is that i'm trying to insert a tweet extracted from `API Twitter` and when I go to do an `INSERT INTO` in a table of a database deployed y `Amazon Web Services - RDS` using `MySQL` as database language and I'm Having the following issue

> ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'es la historia de Isis que decidió hacer un cambio en su vida profesional hacie' at line 3")

My code example is this:

```
INSERT_TWEETS = """INSERT INTO TWEETS (Author_id, Message_id, Message, Date_Time_Tweet, Replys, Retweets, Likes, Quotes)
values({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {});"""

for index, row in tweets.iterrows():                                                      
     db.changeSQL(db="Prueba_Tecnica", query=INSERT_TWEETS.format(row["Author_id"], 
row["Message_id"], str(row["Message"]),row["Date_Time_Tweet"], row["Replys"], row["Retweets"], row["Likes"], row["Quotes"]))`
```

Comment: _Please_ don't use string formatting to build up SQL queries. It leaves you wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). And what is `db.changeSQL`? I don't think that's a standard function... (For that matter, what is `db`?)

Comment: `db` and `changeSQL` are personal functions, db is an instance of the database as an object and `changeSQL` is for modify the database, are like an 'custom' SQLAlchemy perhaps

Comment: Why do you need a custom `db.changeSQL()` function? All it seems to do here is to obscure the actual code that is running. We don't even know which MySQL library you're using.

Comment: In any case, the issue is that you're trying to build queries with string formatting. You don't want `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (some unquoted string)`, you want `INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('some quoted string')`. Instead, please use your library's `cursor.execute()` or `cursor.executemany()` functions, passing parameters in as a separate argument. This avoids the injection issue _and_ takes care of quoting for you. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html, for example.

Answer (score -2):

```
INSERT_TWEETS = """INSERT INTO TWEETS (Author_id, Message_id, Message, Date_Time_Tweet, Replys, Retweets, Likes, Quotes)
values({}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {});"""

for index, row in tweets.iterrows():                                                      
     db.changeSQL(db="Prueba_Tecnica", query=INSERT_TWEETS.format(row["Author_id"], 
row["Message_id"], str(row["Message"]),row["Date_Time_Tweet"], row["Replys"], row["Retweets"], row["Likes"], row["Quotes"]))`
```

Comment: Please [edit] & add more details & explanations to improve the quality of your post, what have you changed? Why did you change it? Avoid posting code-only-answers, please add more details to your answer to help the OP and the future researchers/readers which will encounter the same problem.

Comment: This appears to be identical to the code in the question, right down to the unnecessary trailing `\``.